# Responsive website menu button disappears when phone changed to landscape orientation

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a menu button on a responsive website, but I notice that it disappears on my Samsung phone when orienting from portrait to landscape, with no way to see the navigation links.
This is the mobile css code I am using.  Is there anything that pops out that might be causing the problem.  Thanks for any help.

```
/* RESPONSIVE GRID SYSTEM MOBILE   =====================================================================  */

/*  MAKE LAYOUT RESPONSIVE at 1024px FOR SMALLER    SCREENS ================================================================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

body {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

header {
width: 93.75%; /* 960px / 1024px */
}
#maincontent{
width: 93.75%; /* 960px / 1024px */
}       
.maincontent{
width: 93.75%; /* 960px / 1024px */
}
footer {
width: 93.75%; /* 960px / 1024px */
}
img.image-3-2.features-home-image  {
margin: 1% auto 1% auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 250px;       
}
img.logo-14, img.JVW-Logo, img.JVW-text-line {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
max-width: 250px;
}

.list-holder  {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
width: 60%;
}

ul.unorder-list.unordered-list-1  {
width: 100%;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size: 1.2em; /* 19 / 14 = 1 */
text-indent: -1em;
}   
}

/*  MAKE LAYOUT RESPONSIVE at 768px FOR IPAD       PORTRAIT ================================================================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

body {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

header {
width: 93.75%; /* 720px / 768px */
}
#maincontent{
width: 93.75%; /* 720px / 768px */
}       
.maincontent{
width: 93.75%; /* 720px / 768px */
}       
footer {
width: 93.75%; /* 720px / 768px */
}
img.image-3-2.features-home-image  {
margin: 1% auto 1% auto;
width: 100%;
max-width:200px;        
}

img.logo-14, img.JVW-Logo, img.JVW-text-line {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
max-width: 220px;
}   

.list-holder  {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
width: 70%;
}

ul.unorder-list.unordered-list-1 {
width: 100%;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size: 1.2em; /* 19 / 14 = 1 */
text-indent: -1em;
}
nav { 
height: auto;
}
nav ul {
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: auto;
}
nav li {
width: 50%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
nav li a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
border-right: 1px solid #576979;
}
nav a {
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
text-indent: 25px;
}   
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

body {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
h3 { 
color: #623512;
margin-bottom: 0.3em;
font-size: 1.8em; /* 22 / 29 */
line-height: 1.6em; 
text-align: center; 
}
img.image-3-2.features-home-image  {
margin: 1% auto 1% auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 220px;       
}

img.logo-14, img.JVW-Logo, img.JVW-text-line {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 220px;
}   

.list-holder  {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
width: 60%;
}

ul.unorder-list.unordered-list-1 {
width: 90%;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size: 1.2em; /* 19 / 14 = 1 */
text-indent: -1em;
}
nav { 
height: auto;
}
nav ul {
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: auto;
}
nav li {
width: 50%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
nav li a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
border-right: 1px solid #576979;
}
nav a {
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
text-indent: 25px;
}
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

body {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
h3 { 
color: #623512;
margin-bottom: 0.3em;
font-size: 1.8em; /* 22 / 29 */
line-height: 1.6em; 
text-align: center; 
}
img.image-3-2.features-home-image  {
margin: 1% auto 1% auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 240px;
border: 1px solid green;        
}

img.logo-14, img.JVW-Logo, img.JVW-text-line {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 340px;
}

.list-holder  {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
width: 65%;
}

ul.unorder-list.unordered-list-1 {
width: 90%;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size: 1.2em; /* 24 / 18 = 1 */
text-indent: -1em;
}
nav {
border-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul {
display: none;
height: auto;
}
nav a#pull {
display: block;
background-color: #889097;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
nav a#pull:after {
content: "";
background: url(img/nav-icon.png) no-repeat;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
right: 15px;
top: 10px;
}
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
nav li {
display: block;
float: none;
width: 100%;
}
nav li a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
}
}
```

Comment: Try switching your media queries to min rather.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to coding, having been abandoned by the person building my site.  Would it be possible to give more specifics as to the exact code I should change or where to add.

Answer (score 1):

In your media queries, you can also add `orientation: landscape` or `orientation: portrait` as a condition, so you can set different rules for landscape vs. portrait mode, for example

```
@media only screen and (width:320px) and (height:480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  [... your rules for landscape mode only ... ]
}
```

...and similar for portrait mode

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I thought it might be some simple code that needed to be tweaked, but I guess this is going to be beyond my abilities.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without knowing what element is your menu. But the bug is simple, when you put your Samsung sideways the width of the screen is now larger than 768px and there's no code that seems to change the menu style.

To confirm you can [remotely debug Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) on your Samsung in your PC

Anyway, there are two things from this code that I think you are doing wrong:

1. Responsive "starts" at screen with 1024px

Your design must be always responsive, it does not matter the screen size, otherwise you run in this sort of problems and will probably break the style for users with screen sizes you did not test.

2. Change styles assuming screen sizes

This comment `/*  MAKE LAYOUT RESPONSIVE at 768px FOR IPAD` shows that you are changing things according to screen sizes, that's a bad idea.

Why? Because there's nothing that prevents a manufacturer of creating a device that will be able to open your page with a screen with 784px or 800px. And did you test what happens with those? Probably no.

Real responsive design changes the elements style when *they* can't fit any longer. If your horizontal menu has a minimum width of (or start colliding with other elements at) 945px you change it to a button at this width and not at 768px because that's an iPad screen.

The idea of responsive design is not about putting a menu button on a mobile because that's the trend, but because it does not fit. Follow these two advice and your site will always work for everybody.

And do take care when using `orientation` in your `@media`, as [Mozilla notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation):

> **Note**: This feature does not correspond to **device** orientation. Opening the soft keyboard on many devices in portrait orientation will cause the viewport to become wider than it is tall, thereby causing the browser to use landscape styles instead of portrait.

Comment: Thank you for the great advice.  I will study some of that and see if I can figure out how to code it correctly.

Comment: @Chava One way is to simply resize your browser window. Another, that won't mess with your browser size, is to use the "Device toolbar" in Chrome Dev Tools and selecting the device "Responsive", though I find it much slower than just resizing the window.

Comment: On Firefox the same feature is available, and much faster, as "Responsive Design Mode", fifth button from right at top.